# Python Running SQL Stored Procedure

Tags: python, sql, stored-procedures, pyodbc

I am relatively very new to the world of SQL. I have a stored proc that somebody wrote and I simply want to execute it thru my Python.

Now the stored proc accepts a table as an input and generates two output tables. It works fine and I have tried it in SQL Studio using

```
exec CalcIdxRet_v4  INPUT_TABLE
```

and it works absolutely fine. However when i run it in Python. It works fine and no errors but it ONLY produces one of the 2 output tables. Since there are no errors and still there is one output table only, it is puzzling to me.

Can someone throw some light. Many many thanks

Python code:

```
import pyodbc as db
(username, password, driver, database, server)  = ('xxx', 'xxx', '{ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server}', 'DB', 'ZZZZZ')
conn = db.connect('DRIVER='+driver+'; PORT=1433; SERVER='+server+'; PORT=1443; DATABASE='+database+'; UID='+username+'; PWD='+ password)

cursr = conn.cursor()

sql_btest_1 = ('exec CalcIdxRet_v4  INPUT_TABLE')

cursr.execute(sql_btest_1)
conn.commit()
```

Here is the stored proc

```
USE [DevDB]
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[CalcIdxRet_v4]    Script Date: 12/12/2018 6:46:13 PM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
-- drop table temp
-- create table temp(date date, fs_perm_sec_id varchar(10), weight float)
-- insert into temp values('20160101','aaa',1)
-- [CalcIdxRet_v2b] 'temp'

ALTER procedure [dbo].[CalcIdxRet_v4]

@weightTable varchar(max), 
@retType VARCHAR(25) = null,  -- USD or local
@constTable varchar(max) = null,
@indexTable varchar(max) = null,
@finalDate date = '21000101'

/* Table definitions
- @weightTable: user supplied date, fs_perm_sec_id, weight
- @constTable: the constituent data when all is done
- TempReturns: mirrors @constTable this is where I work
*/
as

-- catch table names with a period
if charindex('.',@weightTable) > 0 GOTO error_one
if charindex('.',@constTable) > 0 GOTO error_one
if charindex('.',@indexTable) > 0 GOTO error_one


-- auto generate output table names
if @constTable is null set @constTable = @weightTable + 'ConstituentReturns'
if @indexTable is null set @indexTable = @weightTable + 'IndexReturns'

/*
 alter view vw_HistPrice_monthly_USD as select date, startDate, endDate, terminationFlag, fs_perm_sec_id, priceRet, divRet, totalRet from HistPrice_monthly
 alter view vw_HistPrice_monthly_local as select date, startDate, endDate, terminationFlag,fs_perm_sec_id, priceRet_local as priceRet, divRet, totalRet_local as totalRet from HistPrice_monthly
 alter view vw_HistPrice_daily_USD as select date, startDate, endDate, terminationFlag,fs_perm_sec_id, priceRet, divRet, totalRet from HistPrice_daily
 alter view vw_HistPrice_daily_local as select date, startDate, endDate, terminationFlag,fs_perm_sec_id, priceRet_local as priceRet, divRet, totalRet_local as totalRet from HistPrice_daily
 alter view vw_HistPriceUS_monthly_USD as select date, startDate, endDate, terminationFlag,fs_perm_sec_id, priceRet, divRet, totalRet from HistPriceUS_monthly
 alter view vw_HistPriceUS_daily_USD as select date, startDate, endDate, terminationFlag,fs_perm_sec_id, priceRet, divRet, totalRet from HistPriceUS_daily
*/

declare @DynamicSQL nvarchar(max)
declare @startDate date = '19000101'
declare @startDatePrev date = '19000101'
declare @endDate date
declare @interimDate date
declare @interimDatePrev date
declare @schema varchar(20) = (select SCHEMA_NAME())
declare @temp varchar(25) = (select @schema + '.temp_returns')
declare @error int = 0

set @weightTable = (select @schema + '.' + @weightTable)
set @constTable = (select @schema + '.' + @constTable)
set @indexTable = (select @schema + '.' + @indexTable)

if charindex('#',@weightTable) > 0  -- if temp table used for table weights, schema is wrong
begin 
    set @weightTable = (select 'tempdb.' + @schema + '.' + 
        substring(@weightTable,(select charindex('#',@weightTable)),(select DATALENGTH(@weightTable))))
end


IF OBJECT_ID(@temp, 'U') IS NOT NULL
begin 
    set @DynamicSQL = 'DROP TABLE ' + @temp;
    exec (@DynamicSQL)
end

------------------------------------
-- Ensure proper inputs
------------------------------------

-- ill-specified weighting table
set @DynamicSQL = 
'set @error0 = (select case when OBJECT_ID ('''+@weightTable+''', ''U'') IS NULL then 1 else 0 end)'
EXECUTE sp_executesql @DynamicSQL, N'@error0 bit OUTPUT', @error0=@error OUTPUT

if @error = 1 goto error_three


-- wrong columns
CREATE TABLE #cols(column_name varchar(500), IsDate int, IsNum int, IsChar Int)

SET @DynamicSQL = 
    'INSERT INTO #cols
    SELECT column_name
    , case when datetime_precision is not null then 1 else 0 end as IsDate
    , case when numeric_precision is not null then 1 else 0 end as IsNum
    , case when character_maximum_length is not null then 1 else 0 end as IsChar
    FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
    WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA+''.''+TABLE_NAME = '''+@weightTable+''''
EXEC(@DynamicSQL)

set @error = (
    select 3-sum(case when column_name = 'date' and IsDate > 0 then 1 else 0 end)
        -  sum(case when column_name = 'fs_perm_sec_id' and IsChar > 0 then 1 else 0 end)
        - sum(case when column_name = 'weight' and IsNum > 0 then 1 else 0 end) as error
    from #cols
)
if @error > 0 goto error_five


-- non-unique date / fs_perm_sec_id
set @DynamicSQL =
'select @error0 = count(*)
from (
    SELECT date, fs_perm_sec_id, COUNT(*) as ct
    FROM ' + @weightTable +
    ' GROUP BY date, fs_perm_sec_id
    HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
) as a'
EXECUTE sp_executesql @DynamicSQL, N'@error0 int OUTPUT', @error0=@error OUTPUT

if @error > 0 goto error_four





------------------------------------
-- Copy table structure from Returns
------------------------------------
-- what type of returns are calculating?
SET @DynamicSQL = 'select top 0 date, startDate, endDate, terminationFlag, fs_perm_sec_id, priceRet_local, totalRet_local, fxRet, priceRet as priceRet_USD, totalRet as totalRet_USD INTO ' + @temp + ' from HistPrice_daily';
exec (@DynamicSQL)

SET @DynamicSQL = 'alter table ' + @temp + ' add weightOpen float, weightClose float'
exec (@DynamicSQL)

SET @DynamicSQL = 'alter table ' + @temp + ' alter column enddate date'
exec (@DynamicSQL)

SET @DynamicSQL = 'SELECT top 0 * INTO ' + @constTable + ' FROM ' + @temp;
exec (@DynamicSQL)


------------------------------------
-- Pre-Allocate Returns for Speed
------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE #RetTable
(   date DATE
    , startDate DATE
    , endDate DATE
    , terminationFlag BIT
    , fs_perm_sec_id VARCHAR(50)
    , priceRet_local FLOAT
    , totalRet_local FLOAT
    , fxRet FLOAT
    , priceRet_usd FLOAT
    , totalRet_usd FLOAT

)


set @DynamicSQL =
    'insert into #RetTable
    select date, startDate, endDate, terminationFlag, fs_perm_sec_id, priceRet_local, totalRet_local, case when currency = ''USD'' then 1 else fxRet end as fxRet, priceRet, totalRet
    from HistPrice_daily as a
    where fs_perm_sec_id in (select fs_perm_sec_id from ' + @weightTable + ')
    and priceRet is not null'
exec (@DynamicSQL)


set @DynamicSQL =
    'insert into #RetTable
    select date, startDate, endDate, terminationFlag, fs_perm_sec_id, priceRet_local, totalRet_local, case when currency = ''USD'' then 1 else fxRet end as fxRet, priceRet_local as priceRet, totalRet_local as totalRet
    from HistPriceUS_daily as a
    where fs_perm_sec_id in (select fs_perm_sec_id from ' + @weightTable + ')
    and priceRet is not null'
exec (@DynamicSQL)

CREATE INDEX idx ON #RetTable(fs_perm_sec_id,startDate)


------------------------------------
-- Initial start and end date
------------------------------------
set @DynamicSQL = 
'select @date = min(date) from ' + @weightTable +
' where date > (select coalesce(max(date),''19000101'') from ' + @constTable + ')'
EXECUTE sp_executesql @DynamicSQL, N'@date date OUTPUT', @date=@startDate OUTPUT

set @DynamicSQL = 
'select @date = coalesce(min(date),''21000101'') from ' + @weightTable +
' where date > ''' + convert(varchar(8),@startDate,112) +''''
EXECUTE sp_executesql @DynamicSQL, N'@date date OUTPUT', @date=@endDate OUTPUT

------------------------------------
-- Loop on rebalance dates
------------------------------------
declare @run bit = 1

if @startDate = '21000101' begin set @run = 0 end

while (@run = 1)
begin

    set @DynamicSQL = 'truncate table ' + @temp;
    exec (@DynamicSQL)

    -- source the dreturns data
    set @DynamicSQL = 
    'insert into ' + @temp + 
    ' select date, startDate, endDate, terminationFlag, fs_perm_sec_id, priceRet_local, totalRet_local, fxRet, priceRet_usd, totalRet_usd
        , null as weightOpen, null as weightClose
    from #RetTable as a
    where startDate between dateadd(d,1,''' + convert(varchar(8),@startDate,112) + ''') and ''' + convert(varchar(8),@endDate,112) +'''
    and fs_perm_sec_id in (select fs_perm_sec_id from ' + @weightTable + ' where date = '''+convert(varchar(8),@startDate,112)+''')
    and priceRet_local is not null'
    exec (@DynamicSQL)



    -- This prevents corp actions prior to being in portfolio
    set @DynamicSQL =
    'delete from ' + @temp + ' where startDate < (select max(endDate) from '  + @constTable + ')'  
    exec (@DynamicSQL)

    ------------------------------------
    -- Fill missing companies
    ------------------------------------

    -- This is really slick, it allows for errant days where a single
    -- company shows up in the pricing table.  On these days, we dummy
    -- a return of 1, so the rest of the portfolio just carries forward!

    set @DynamicSQL = '
    insert into ' + @temp + ' (date, fs_perm_sec_id, priceRet_local, totalRet_local, priceRet_usd, totalRet_usd)
    select *, 1 as priceRet_local, 1 as totalRet_local, 1 as priceRet_usd, 1 as totalRet_usd
    from (
        select *
        from ( select distinct date from ' + @temp + ' ) as a
        join (select distinct fs_perm_sec_id from ' + @weightTable + ' where date = '''+convert(varchar(8),@startDate,112)+''') as b
        on 1=1
        except
        select date, fs_perm_sec_id 
        from ' + @temp + '
    ) as aa

    -- delete past termination 
    delete from ' + @temp + '
    where fs_perm_sec_id + convert(varchar(8),date,112)
    in (
        select a.fs_perm_sec_id + convert(varchar(8),a.date,112)
        from ' + @temp + ' as a
        join ' + @temp + ' as b
        on a.date > b.date and a.fs_perm_sec_id = b.fs_perm_sec_id
        where b.terminationFlag = 1
    )

    -- update enddate
    ;WITH cte AS (SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY date ORDER BY ct DESC) AS rn
              FROM (SELECT date, enddate, COUNT(*) AS ct              
                    FROM ' + @temp + '            
                    GROUP BY date, enddate) AS a
             )
    UPDATE ' + @temp + ' 
    SET enddate = bb.enddate
    FROM ' + @temp + ' AS aa
    JOIN cte AS bb
    ON aa.date = bb.date
    where aa.enddate IS NULL AND bb.rn = 1'
    exec (@DynamicSQL)

    ------------------------------------
    -- Initial weights
    ------------------------------------
    set @DynamicSQL = 
    'update ' + @temp +
    '   set weightOpen = b.weight
    from ' + @temp + ' as a
    join ' + @weightTable + ' as b
    on a.fs_perm_sec_id = b.fs_perm_sec_id
    where a.date = (select min(date) from ' + @temp + ') 
    and b.date = ''' + convert(varchar(8),@startDate,112) + '''';
    exec (@DynamicSQL)


    set @DynamicSQL = 
    'select @date = (select min(date) from ' + @temp + ')'
    EXECUTE sp_executesql @DynamicSQL, N'@date date OUTPUT', @date=@interimDate OUTPUT


    -- normalize weight
    set @DynamicSQL = 
    'update ' + @temp +
    ' set weightOpen = weightOpen / b.wgt
    from ' + @temp + ' as a
    join (
        select date, sum(weightOpen) as wgt
        from ' + @temp + '
        where date = ''' + convert(varchar(8),@interimDate,112) + ''' 
        group by date
    ) as b
    on a.date = b.date

    -- update close
    update ' + @temp + '
    set weightClose = priceRet_usd*weightOpen / div
    from ' + @temp + ' as a
    join (
        select date, sum(priceRet_usd*weightOpen) as div
        from ' + @temp + '
        where date = ''' + convert(varchar(8),@interimDate,112) + ''' 
        group by date
    ) as b
    on a.date = b.date'
    exec (@DynamicSQL)


    ------------------------------------
    -- Loop on intirim dates
    ------------------------------------

    declare @ct int

    set @DynamicSQL = 
    'select @ct2 = (select count(*) from ' + @temp + ' where date > ''' + convert(varchar(8),@interimDate,112) + ''')'
    EXECUTE sp_executesql @DynamicSQL, N'@ct2 int OUTPUT', @ct2=@ct OUTPUT



    while (@ct <> 0)
    begin 
        select @interimDatePrev = @interimDate
        --select @interimDate = min(date) from TempReturns where date > @interimDatePrev

        set @DynamicSQL = 
        'select @date = (select min(date) from ' + @temp + ' where date > ''' + convert(varchar(8),@interimDate,112) + ''')'
        EXECUTE sp_executesql @DynamicSQL, N'@date date OUTPUT', @date=@interimDate OUTPUT

        -- push forward weights
        set @DynamicSQL =
        'update a 
        set weightOpen = b.weightClose
        from ' + @temp + ' as a
        join ' + @temp + ' as b
        on a.fs_perm_sec_id = b.fs_perm_sec_id
        where a.date = ''' + convert(varchar(8),@interimDate,112) + ''' 
            and b.date = ''' + convert(varchar(8),@interimDatePrev,112) + ''''
        exec(@DynamicSQL)

        -- update in case something was terminated
        set @DynamicSQL =
        'update a
        set weightOpen = weightOpen / b.wgt
        from ' + @temp + ' as a
        join (
            select date, sum(weightOpen) as wgt
            from ' + @temp + '
            where date = ''' + convert(varchar(8),@interimDate,112) + ''' 
            group by date
        ) as b
        on a.date = b.date'
        exec(@DynamicSQL)

        -- update close
        set @DynamicSQL =
        'update a
        set weightClose = priceRet_usd*weightOpen / div
        from ' + @temp + ' as a
        join (
            select date, sum(priceRet_usd*weightOpen) as div
            from ' + @temp + '
            where date = ''' + convert(varchar(8),@interimDate,112) + ''' 
            group by date
        ) as b
        on a.date = b.date'
        exec(@DynamicSQL)

    set @DynamicSQL = 
    'select @ct2 = (select count(*) from ' + @temp + ' where date > ''' + convert(varchar(8),@interimDate,112) + ''')'
    EXECUTE sp_executesql @DynamicSQL, N'@ct2 int OUTPUT', @ct2=@ct OUTPUT


    end
    -------------
    -- END WHILE
    ------------

    set @DynamicSQL = 'insert into ' + @constTable + ' select * from ' + @temp
    exec(@DynamicSQL)


    -------------------
    -- update dates
    -------------------
    -- If there is no end date, we set end date to 2100-01-01 and the portfolio gets
    -- computed all of the way out.  If there is rebalance date more recent than the
    -- max date in constituent table, then start date to 2100-01-01.  This is our 
    -- flag to end loop
    set @startDatePrev = @startDate

    set @DynamicSQL = 
    'select @date = coalesce(min(date),''21000101'') from ' + @weightTable +
    ' where date >= (select max(Date) from ' + @constTable + ')'
    EXECUTE sp_executesql @DynamicSQL, N'@date date OUTPUT', @date=@startDate OUTPUT

    set @DynamicSQL = 
    'select @date = coalesce(min(date),''21000101'') from ' + @weightTable +
    ' where date > ''' + convert(varchar(8),@startDate,112) +''''
    EXECUTE sp_executesql @DynamicSQL, N'@date date OUTPUT', @date=@endDate OUTPUT

    if @endDate >= @finalDate set @endDate = @finalDate
    if @startDate >= @finalDate set @run = 0
    if @startDate in('21000101',@startDatePrev) set @run = 0


end
-------------
-- END WHILE
------------
set @DynamicSQL = 'drop table ' + @temp;
exec(@DynamicSQL)

print('constituents done')
-------------
-- Aggregate
-------------
declare @datePrev date
declare @date date

set @DynamicSQL =
'select min(endDate) as date
     , count(*) as constituents
     , sum(weightOpen) as weightOpen
     , sum(weightClose) as weightClose
     , sum(weightOpen * priceRet_local) as priceRet_local
     , sum(weightOpen * totalRet_local) as totalRet_local
     , sum(weightOpen * fxRet) as fxRet
     , sum(weightOpen * priceRet_usd) as priceRet_usd
     , sum(weightOpen * totalRet_usd) as totalRet_usd

into ' + @indexTable +
' from ' + @constTable +
' group by date'
exec (@DynamicSQL)

set @DynamicSQL =
'delete from ' + @indexTable + ' where date is null'
exec(@DynamicSQL)

set @DynamicSQL =
'alter table ' + @indexTable +
' add priceIdxLevel_local numeric(16,8)
    , trIdxLevel_local numeric(16,8)
    , priceIdxLevel_usd numeric(16,8)
    , trIdxLevel_usd numeric(16,8)'
exec (@DynamicSQL)

set @DynamicSQL =
'insert into ' + @indexTable + ' (date, priceIdxLevel_local,trIdxLevel_local,priceIdxLevel_usd, trIdxLevel_usd)
select (select min(startdate) from ' + @constTable + '),100,100,100,100'
exec (@DynamicSQL)

set @DynamicSQL = 
'select @date = (select max(date) from ' + @indexTable + ' where priceIdxLevel_local is not null)'
EXECUTE sp_executesql @DynamicSQL, N'@date date OUTPUT', @date=@datePrev OUTPUT

set @DynamicSQL = 
'select @date2 = (select min(date) from ' + @indexTable + ' where date > ''' + convert(varchar(8),@datePrev,112) + ''')'
EXECUTE sp_executesql @DynamicSQL, N'@date2 date OUTPUT', @date2=@date OUTPUT


set @run = 1
while (@run = 1)
begin

    set @DynamicSQL =
    'update a
    set priceIdxLevel_local = b.priceIdxLevel_local*a.priceRet_local
        , trIdxLevel_local = b.trIdxLevel_local*a.totalRet_local
        , priceIdxLevel_usd = b.priceIdxLevel_usd*a.priceRet_usd
        , trIdxLevel_usd = b.trIdxLevel_usd*a.totalRet_usd
    from ' + @indexTable + ' as a
    join ' + @indexTable + ' as b
    on a.date = ''' + convert(varchar(8),@date,112) + ''' and 
        b.date = ''' + convert(varchar(8),@datePrev,112) + ''''
    exec(@DynamicSQL)

    set @datePrev = @date


    set @DynamicSQL = 
    'select @date2 = (select coalesce(min(date),''21000101'') from ' + @indexTable + 
    ' where date > ''' + convert(varchar(8),@datePrev,112) + ''')'
    EXECUTE sp_executesql @DynamicSQL, N'@date2 date OUTPUT', @date2=@date OUTPUT

    if @date = '21000101' begin set @run = 0 end
end


------------------------
-- Backwards Compatability
------------------------
if @retType = 'USD'
begin
    set @DynamicSQL = 'alter table ' + @constTable +' drop column priceRet_local'
    exec(@DynamicSQL)
    set @DynamicSQL = 'alter table ' + @constTable +' drop column totalRet_local'
    exec(@DynamicSQL)
    set @DynamicSQL = 'alter table ' + @constTable +' drop column fxRet'
    exec(@DynamicSQL)
    set @DynamicSQL = 'alter table ' + @indexTable +' drop column priceRet_local'
    exec(@DynamicSQL)
    set @DynamicSQL = 'alter table ' + @indexTable +' drop column totalRet_local'
    exec(@DynamicSQL)
    set @DynamicSQL = 'alter table ' + @indexTable +' drop column fxRet'
    exec(@DynamicSQL)
    set @DynamicSQL = 'alter table ' + @indexTable +' drop column priceIdxLevel_local'
    exec(@DynamicSQL)
    set @DynamicSQL = 'alter table ' + @indexTable +' drop column trIdxLevel_local'
    exec(@DynamicSQL)

    set @DynamicSQL = 'sp_rename ''' + @constTable +'.priceRet_USD'',''priceRet'',''COLUMN'''
    exec(@DynamicSQL)
    set @DynamicSQL = 'sp_rename ''' + @constTable +'.totalRet_USD'',''totalRet'',''COLUMN'''
    exec(@DynamicSQL)
    set @DynamicSQL = 'sp_rename ''' + @indexTable +'.priceRet_usd'',''priceRet'',''COLUMN'''
    exec(@DynamicSQL)
    set @DynamicSQL = 'sp_rename ''' + @indexTable +'.totalRet_usd'',''totalRet'',''COLUMN'''
    exec(@DynamicSQL)
    set @DynamicSQL = 'sp_rename ''' + @indexTable +'.priceIdxLevel_USD'',''priceIdxLevel'',''COLUMN'''
    exec(@DynamicSQL)
    set @DynamicSQL = 'sp_rename ''' + @indexTable +'.trIdxLevel_USD'',''trIdxLevel'',''COLUMN'''
    exec(@DynamicSQL)
end

if @retType = 'local'
begin
    set @DynamicSQL = 'alter table ' + @constTable +' drop column priceRet_USD'
    exec(@DynamicSQL)
    set @DynamicSQL = 'alter table ' + @constTable +' drop column totalRet_USD'
    exec(@DynamicSQL)
    set @DynamicSQL = 'alter table ' + @constTable +' drop column fxRet'
    exec(@DynamicSQL)
    set @DynamicSQL = 'alter table ' + @indexTable +' drop column priceRet_USD'
    exec(@DynamicSQL)
    set @DynamicSQL = 'alter table ' + @indexTable +' drop column totalRet_USD'
    exec(@DynamicSQL)
    set @DynamicSQL = 'alter table ' + @indexTable +' drop column fxRet'
    exec(@DynamicSQL)
    set @DynamicSQL = 'alter table ' + @indexTable +' drop column priceIdxLevel_USD'
    exec(@DynamicSQL)
    set @DynamicSQL = 'alter table ' + @indexTable +' drop column trIdxLevel_USD'
    exec(@DynamicSQL)

    set @DynamicSQL = 'sp_rename ''' + @constTable +'.priceRet_local'',''priceRet'',''COLUMN'''
    exec(@DynamicSQL)
    set @DynamicSQL = 'sp_rename ''' + @constTable +'.totalRet_local'',''totalRet'',''COLUMN'''
    exec(@DynamicSQL)
    set @DynamicSQL = 'sp_rename ''' + @indexTable +'.priceRet_local'',''priceRet'',''COLUMN'''
    exec(@DynamicSQL)
    set @DynamicSQL = 'sp_rename ''' + @indexTable +'.totalRet_local'',''totalRet'',''COLUMN'''
    exec(@DynamicSQL)
    set @DynamicSQL = 'sp_rename ''' + @indexTable +'.priceIdxLevel_local'',''priceIdxLevel'',''COLUMN'''
    exec(@DynamicSQL)
    set @DynamicSQL = 'sp_rename ''' + @indexTable +'.trIdxLevel_local'',''trIdxLevel'',''COLUMN'''
    exec(@DynamicSQL)
end


GOTO clean_exit


------------------------
-- Error codes
------------------------

error_one:
print('Input or output table names should not include schema!')
return

error_two:
print('Input frequency or return type is unknown!')
return

error_three:
print('The weighting table does not exist!')
return

error_four:
print('The security and date combinations in the weighting table are not unique.')
return

error_five:
print('The weighting table is not correctly specified.  
    It needs a date column called date, 
    a char column called fs_perm_sec_id, 
    and a numeric column called weight.')
return

clean_exit:
print('Returns procedure is done.')
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use cursr.fetchall() to get all the rowsets, and use cursr.nextset() to get the second one.

See details here: https://www.easysoft.com/developer/languages/python/examples/CallSPMultiResultSet.html

Comment: Thanks, however just to be clear from my side. This stored proc is not returning any output. It simply creates two new tables in the schema. Now when I run thru Python only one table is being generated and not the other one. The way this stored proc works is that it creates 1st table, writes it to the DB and then creates the 2nd table (based on the data in the 1st table) and writes the 2nd table too. It is the 1st tables that is being only created in the database when running thru Python

Comment: Ah ok. Could you post the stored procedure code that is creating the tables?

Comment: Added in the post above. Thanks!

Comment: Had a quick look at the code. Are the tables you are attempting to save the #col and #RetTable? Using the # character in this way means they are temporary tables, and so will be deleted on the session closing. I can't see any other tables being created. If I am wrong, could you let me know where you are defining the tables in question.

Comment: Thanks. There are some temp tables that are created in the Stored Proc but ultimately it creates two final tables "INPUT_TABLEConstituentReturns" & "INPUT_TABLEIndexReturns". It is the 1st table that is being created by Python while running the same stored proc thru SQL studio creates both tables. What is extremely puzzling to me is --- Python is executing the stored proc query on the SQL Server thus Python is not even thinking its the SQL which is doing the job so how come results are different?

Comment: Ok, so my guess is that it is encountering an error, and because you are using PRINT it isn't being communicated to pyodbc. Change the PRINTs at the end in your error handling to RAISERROR() instead and it should fail and give you the correct error message. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/raiserror-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: If it isn't that. Are you connecting through python using the same log on as you are using on SSMS?

Comment: Yes, connection is fine (and I use same conn string for multiple other instances which work fine) as python still runs the proc (no errors) and the 1st table is being created, its just the 2nd table that is not being created

Comment: Did you try using the RAISERROR function? I think if where you are using "if @error = 1 GOTO error_three" encounters an error it will just end the function as though there was no error. So it will execute the code up to the point where the first table is created, then it will encounter an error and PRINT a message. Since you are not capturing the message in Python, pyodbc will execute as if there is no error. Alternatively, you could capture and print the messages in python. If it runs without error then you should see the 'Returns procedure is done.'